# Como ajustar o meu aplicativo ao tamanho da tela de vários dispositivos?

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragment

Boa tarde, estou desenvolvendo um aplicativo no Android Studio e ele fica bem ajustado em meu Motorola Moto X 2ª Geração. Porém, em meu Samsung Galaxy Note 3, Motorola Moto E e Motorola Moto G, ele fica todo desalinhado, fica uma bagunça!
Gostaria de saber como fazer ele se ajustar em todos os dispositivos que eu quiser.
Por favor, especifique bem como eu faço, pois sou novato em Android Studio.

Comment: Bem vindo, veja como fazer uma boa pergunta http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: @lucas-medina veja se esse link ajuda http://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/131295/problemas-com-o-layout-da-aplica%C3%A7%C3%A3o-em-diversos-celulares/134290#134290

Answer (score -1):

Já consegui, adicionei isto no AndroidManifest.xml

```
<supports-screens android:smallScreens="true"
                  android:normalScreens="true"
                  android:largeScreens="true"
                  android:xlargeScreens="true"
                  android:anyDensity="true"
                  android:resizeable="true"/>
```

Funcionou perfeitamente!

Comment: It doesn't work for me.