# Problemas com o layout da aplicação em diversos celulares

Tags: android, android-layout

Estou com um aplicativo que fiz e emulei usando meu celular lg g2 mini, quando emulo ele fica tudo direitinho, o formulário do jeito que projetei no seu devido canto. Quando instalo o mesmo apk em outros celulares, a aplicação perde o layout ficando um botão por cima de uma imagem, o formulário bagunçado. Alguém sabe informar o que é preciso fazer para que a aplicação funcione conforme desenhado no meu layout sirva para todos os modelos de celulares?

[image: erro]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="@color/black"
    android:text="Endereço: Rua João Henrique da Silva, 11 - Pajuçara - "
    android:id="@+id/textView8"
    android:textSize="12dp"
    android:textAlignment="center"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/nome1"
    android:textColorHint="#9b9a9a"
    android:hint="*Nome:"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:textColorLink="#050000"
    android:backgroundTint="#020000"
    android:textColor="#050000"
    android:layout_above="@+id/email"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/msg"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/msg"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/msg" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColorHint="#9b9a9a"
    android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/email"
    android:hint="*E-mail:"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:textColorLink="#050000"
    android:backgroundTint="#020000"
    android:textColor="#050000"
    android:layout_above="@+id/msg"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/msg"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/msg"
    android:layout_marginBottom="36dp"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/msg"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/msg" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColorHint="#9b9a9a"
    android:inputType="phone"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/telefone"
    android:hint="Telefone:"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:textColorLink="#050000"
    android:backgroundTint="#020000"
    android:textColor="#050000"
    android:layout_above="@+id/nome1"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/msg"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/msg"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/msg" />

<Button
    android:layout_width="85dp"
    android:layout_height="40dp"
    android:text="Enviar"
    android:id="@+id/send"
    android:layout_above="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/textView8" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColorHint="#9b9a9a"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/endereco"
    android:hint="Endereço:"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:textColorLink="#050000"
    android:backgroundTint="#020000"
    android:textColor="#050000"
    android:layout_above="@+id/telefone"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/msg"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/msg"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/msg" />

<EditText
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="120dp"
    android:gravity="top"
    android:inputType="textMultiLine"
    android:lines="5"
    android:ems="10"
    android:id="@+id/msg"
    android:hint="*Mensagem"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:textColorHint="#9b9a9a"
    android:layout_above="@+id/send"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/send"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/send"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/textView8"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/textView8"
    android:backgroundTint="#020000"
    android:textColor="#050000"
    android:textColorLink="#050000" />

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="150dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:src="@drawable/lg"
    android:layout_above="@+id/spinner" />

<Spinner
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/spinner"
    android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
    android:visibility="visible"
    android:theme="@style/Animation.AppCompat.DropDownUp"
    android:background="@color/colorFABPressed"
    android:layout_above="@+id/endereco"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/send"
    android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/send"
    />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Agendar para:"
    android:id="@+id/textView10"
    android:textColor="#010101"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/endereco"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_marginLeft="53dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="53dp" />

<ImageButton
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
    android:src="@drawable/previe"
    android:background="#00000000"
    android:layout_above="@+id/msg"
    android:layout_toEndOf="@+id/imageView"
    android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/imageView" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
    android:text="Capturar imagem"
    android:id="@+id/textView16"
    android:textColor="#010101"
    android:textSize="14dp"
    android:layout_above="@+id/msg"
    android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/send"
    android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/send" />
```

Eu projeto meus xmls ja verificando como ficaria em cada tipo de tela. Conforme imagem abaixo
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e aqui esta normal

Comment: Poderia mostrar como projetou o seu layout?

Comment: @Carlos, vê se esse link te ajuda: https://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Comment: isso ocorre devido os diferentes tamanhos de tela você precisa emular em diferentes tamanhos de celulares https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
no site acima voce vai encontrar como fazer isso

Comment: Eu percebi que até a função de tirar foto não funcionou em alguns celulares.. Ele encerra o apk quando a foto é tirada. Alguém tem uma solução mais precisa quanto a isso? É preciso emular pra vários tipos de tamanhos?

Comment: Julio meu xml estao todos como relative e com wrap_content mas ainda sim ta bugada

Comment: @CarlosDiego edite a pergunta e coloque o layout para podermos verificar com calma?

Comment: Mateus conforme a imagem acima, meu apk está rodando em alguns celulares, como exemplo o meu lg2mini e o lg4 rodou de boa todos os layouts, agora em celulares com resolução menor ficar todo distorcido, formulário bagunçado, botos fora do canto, texto escondido. Gostaria de uma solução mais direta, pois as que aparecerão me deixaram boiando um pouco.

Comment: @CarlosDiego está rodando em alguns celulares corretamente não significa que o layout está bem projetado (não está, é claro). Sem o arquivo de layout fica difícil de te ajudar. Não tem uma resposta direta. Android é trabalhoso. A solução porca seria você criar um layout para ldpi, outro para mdpi, hdpi etc.

Comment: Mateus anexei meu arquivo xml. Tem como conversarmos via chat?

Comment: @CarlosDiego vou analisar com calma. Mas, olhei uma coisa e não gostei: nunca use t layout_toLeftOf junto com o android:layout_toStartOf mesma coisa para o para Right e End. Você terá problemas de compatibilidade. Minha sugestão: utilize o mais recente: start e end só. Tire os left e right e teste para ver. Seu Android Lint do Android Studio não reclamou disso?

Comment: Farei isso, ainda nao tenho o lint instalado

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Primeira Opção** - O que você terá que fazer, é criar uma tela para cada tipo de orientação **Portrait**(Retrato - Em Pé!) e uma para **Land**(Paisagem - De lado).

Exemplo:

No seu diretório /res/ você pode ter duas pastas, exemplo:

- /res/layout -> Tela no Modo Padrão "Retrato".
- /res/layout-land -> Tela no Modo Paisagem.

---

Esse é o arquivo `fragment_test.xml` da pasta `res/layout` e é para a orientação padrão **Portrait**(Retrato), e serve para dispositivos com resolução menor -> Smartphone:

```
    <RelativeLayout
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        tools:context=".testFragment">

        <ScrollView
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <FrameLayout
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="08dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="08dp"
            android:paddingTop="08dp"
            android:paddingBottom="08dp">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/nome1"
            android:textColorHint="#9b9a9a"
            android:hint="*Nome:"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColorLink="#050000"
            android:backgroundTint="#020000"
            android:textColor="#050000"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left"
            android:layout_marginTop="170dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:src="@drawable/previe"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center|right"
            android:layout_marginTop="390dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Agendar para:"
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:textColor="#010101"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp" />

            <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:textColorHint="#9b9a9a"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/endereco"
            android:hint="Endereço:"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColorLink="#050000"
            android:backgroundTint="#020000"
            android:textColor="#050000"
            android:layout_above="@+id/telefone"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/msg"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/msg"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/msg"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="320dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Enviar"
            android:id="@+id/send"
            android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|right"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="500dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:text="Endereço: Rua , Numero - Localidade"
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="550dp" />

            <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:textColorHint="#9b9a9a"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/telefone"
            android:hint="Telefone:"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColorLink="#050000"
            android:backgroundTint="#020000"
            android:textColor="#050000"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="270dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="82dp"
                android:gravity="top"
                android:inputType="textMultiLine"
                android:lines="5"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/msg"
                android:hint="*Mensagem"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColorHint="#9b9a9a"
                android:backgroundTint="#020000"
                android:textColor="#050000"
                android:textColorLink="#050000"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center"
                android:layout_marginTop="410dp" />

            <EditText
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:textColorHint="#9b9a9a"
                android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
                android:ems="10"
                android:id="@+id/email"
                android:hint="*E-mail:"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:textColorLink="#050000"
                android:backgroundTint="#020000"
                android:textColor="#050000"
                android:layout_gravity="left|top"
                android:layout_marginTop="220dp" />

            <Spinner
                android:layout_width="190dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/spinner"
                android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
                android:visibility="visible"
                android:theme="@style/Animation.AppCompat.DropDownUp"
                android:background="@color/colorFABPressed"
                android:layout_above="@+id/endereco"
                android:layout_alignRight="@+id/send"
                android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/send"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
                android:layout_marginTop="101dp"
                android:layout_marginLeft="80dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="410dp"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:src="@drawable/lg"
                android:layout_above="@+id/spinner"
                android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

            <TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
                android:text="Capturar imagem"
                android:id="@+id/textView16"
                android:textColor="#010101"
                android:textSize="14sp"
                android:layout_gravity="top|center|right"
                android:layout_marginTop="390dp"
                android:layout_marginRight="120dp" />

        </FrameLayout>
     </ScrollView>
   </RelativeLayout>
```

> **Obs:** Seus textos não estão externalizados, ex: `android:text="Capturar imagem"`, o que não é recomendado pelo Google, externalize-os através do Recurso de `String Name` no diretório /values/ em `strings.xml`, dessa maneira:
>
> ```
> <resources>
>        <string name="capturar">Capturar imagem</string>
> </resources>
> ```
>
> E na sua tela você troca o trecho do código para
>   `android:text="@string/capturar"`.

**Resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

---

Esse é o arquivo `fragment_test.xml(land)` da pasta `res/layout-land` e é para a orientação **Land**(Paisagem), e que se adapta melhor a dispositivos de 7, 8 e 10 polegadas -> Tablets:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".testFragment">

    <ScrollView
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="08dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="08dp"
        android:paddingTop="08dp"
        android:paddingBottom="08dp">

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/nome1"
            android:textColorHint="#9b9a9a"
            android:hint="*Nome:"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColorLink="#050000"
            android:backgroundTint="#020000"
            android:textColor="#050000"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left"
            android:layout_marginTop="170dp" />

        <ImageButton
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/imageButton2"
            android:src="@drawable/previe"
            android:background="#00000000"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center|right"
            android:layout_marginTop="390dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="60dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Agendar para:"
            android:id="@+id/textView10"
            android:textColor="#010101"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="60dp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="120dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:textColorHint="#9b9a9a"
            android:inputType="textPersonName"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/endereco"
            android:hint="Endereço:"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColorLink="#050000"
            android:backgroundTint="#020000"
            android:textColor="#050000"
            android:layout_above="@+id/telefone"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/msg"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/msg"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/msg"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="320dp" />

        <Button
            android:layout_width="85dp"
            android:layout_height="40dp"
            android:text="Enviar"
            android:id="@+id/send"
            android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|right"
            android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="500dp" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:text="Endereço: Rua , Numero - Localidade"
            android:id="@+id/textView8"
            android:textSize="12sp"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_gravity="top|bottom|center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
            android:layout_marginTop="550dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:textColorHint="#9b9a9a"
            android:inputType="phone"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/telefone"
            android:hint="Telefone:"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColorLink="#050000"
            android:backgroundTint="#020000"
            android:textColor="#050000"
            android:layout_gravity="top|left|center_vertical"
            android:layout_marginTop="270dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="82dp"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:inputType="textMultiLine"
            android:lines="5"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/msg"
            android:hint="*Mensagem"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColorHint="#9b9a9a"
            android:backgroundTint="#020000"
            android:textColor="#050000"
            android:textColorLink="#050000"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center"
            android:layout_marginTop="410dp" />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:textColorHint="#9b9a9a"
            android:inputType="textPostalAddress"
            android:ems="10"
            android:id="@+id/email"
            android:hint="*E-mail:"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:textColorLink="#050000"
            android:backgroundTint="#020000"
            android:textColor="#050000"
            android:layout_gravity="left|top"
            android:layout_marginTop="220dp" />

        <Spinner
            android:layout_width="290dp"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:id="@+id/spinner"
            android:spinnerMode="dropdown"
            android:visibility="visible"
            android:theme="@style/Animation.AppCompat.DropDownUp"
            android:background="@color/colorFABPressed"
            android:layout_above="@+id/endereco"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/send"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/send"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top"
            android:layout_marginTop="101dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="80dp" />

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="410dp"
            android:layout_height="100dp"
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
            android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
            android:src="@drawable/lg"
            android:layout_above="@+id/spinner"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal|top" />

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge"
            android:text="Capturar imagem"
            android:id="@+id/textView16"
            android:textColor="#010101"
            android:textSize="14sp"
            android:layout_gravity="top|center|right"
            android:layout_marginTop="390dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="120dp" />

    </FrameLayout>
    </ScrollView>
</RelativeLayout>
```

> **Obs:** Seus textos não estão externalizados, ex: `android:text="Capturar imagem"`, o que não é recomendado pelo Google, externalize-os através do Recurso de `String Name` no diretório /values/ em `strings.xml`, dessa maneira:
>
> ```
> <resources>
>        <string name="capturar">Capturar imagem</string>
> </resources>
> ```
>
> E na sua tela você troca o trecho do código para
>   `android:text="@string/capturar"`.

**Resultado:**

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Obs: Recomendo que sempre que possível teste seus aplicativos em dispositivos reais com resoluções diferentes ou em máquinas virtuais com configurações e resoluções diferentes, para ver se está tudo correto, garantindo assim a qualidade de seus aplicativos.**

---

**Segunda Opção** - Se você não sabe como criar uma tela para cada tipo de orientação, você pode fazer com que suas `Activities` trabalharem somente com a orientação **Portrait** no arquivo **AndroidManifest.xml**, desse jeito o seu layout sempre ficará "correto", já que sua visualização será sempre na orientação **Portrait**(Retrato), mas, fazendo desse jeito, não será permitido que a pessoa vire a tela de seu aplicativo, o que não é uma boa prática, mas pelo menos resolve o problema, como nesse exemplo:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="br.com.novoapp">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">

        <activity
            android:screenOrientation="portrait"
            android:name=".SplashScreen"
            android:label="@string/app_name" >

            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:label="@string/app_name"
            android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Veja que acima a Activity(atividade) -> `.SplashScreen` é iniciada em orientação portrait(`android:screenOrientation="portrait"`), logicamente por ela ser uma tela de SplashScreen, agora você pode também fazer com que sua `.MainActivity` trabalhe com na orientação `portrait` e fique assim, não permitindo que se vire a tela quando o usuário virar o celular de lado, o que não é uma boa prática, mas resolve.

Basta adicionar a sua `.MainActivity` o trecho `android:screenOrientation="portrait"`, dessa maneira:

```
            <activity
                android:screenOrientation="portrait"
                android:name=".MainActivity"
                android:label="@string/app_name"
                android:theme="@style/AppTheme.NoActionBar">
            </activity>
```

> **Obs:** Lembrando que sua tela `activity_main.xml` que faz parte de sua 
>   Activity -> `.MainActivity` que está em orientação **Portrait** não deve estar estourando `Layout` em nenhum dispositivo, para que o resultado na orientação **Portrait**(Retrato) fique padrão em todos os dispositivos.

---

Espero ter ajudado!